# setting self variables based on each other

Tags: python, class, oop, self

quick question in python
let's say my class goes like this

```
class Enemy():
   def __init__(self, level):
      self.level = level
      self.damage = self.level + 5
```

the thing is that since the self.damage value is instantiated once it will not update when self.level is changed, how can I make it do just that? I tried searching online but I have no idea what this is called so I cannot find any help

Comment: Make `damage` a method that returns `self.level + 5`.

Comment: you could use a `@property` to make a function that behaves like a property and allow for some more complicated behaviour

Comment: @ScottHunter but wouldn't I have to call this method everytime I level up?

Comment: @Macattack i'll check this out right now!

Comment: No; you would call it every time you want to know the value of `damage`.

Comment: @ScottHunter by doing so do I need to remove the self.damage = self.level + 5 from the init method? because then how would i be able to print the value just by calling it like i would with self.level

Comment: @Yikes That's what properties are for - Macattack's comment is good advice

Comment: @Alan Ok thank you i guess this is the answer to my question the, but it just seems overly complicated for something pretty simple that is what makes me hesitant

Comment: @Yikes The property decorator is simple once you are used to it and gives a nice safe way to get or set attribute values. It's highly recommended you learn how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [properties](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property). Maybe you know getter and setter methods from other programming languages. Properties are the Python equivalent of them. In this case, you only need a getter method.

```py
class Enemy():
   def __init__(self, level):
      self.level = level

   @property
   def damage(self):
      return self.level + 5
```

The beauty is, you can still access `damage` as an attribute on your instance like `enemy.damage`, without having to explicitly call the method, it's done automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice article about [properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property):
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-property-decorator/

They allow you to control how attributes are accessed, which makes it easier to update them in the future if you decide a change in needed. For example, instead of being a flat +5, you can change the value or make it variable and anything that calls the attribute will not be affected.

Later you can add a way of manually setting the damage if you wanted to, through the use of `@damage.setter`.

```
class Enemy():
  '''This holds the data and functionality for enemies'''

  def __init__(self, level):
    self.level = level
    # Show the damage being set
    print(self.damage)

  @property
  def damage(self):
    return self.level + 5
```

Comment: You can't assign an int value to self.damage, that's the property. Running this snippet actually yields an AttributeError.

Comment: You're right, didn't save my last change. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using properties, you can also make damage a function rather than a variable:

```
def damage():
    return self.level + 5
```